# ImageButton With Mouse Event Handlers Considered Not Well Formed

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

ASP.NET says that the following ImageButton server tag is not well formed:

```
<asp:TableCell VerticalAlign="Top">
    <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="imgAdd" src="Images/add_plus_1.gif"
        onmouseout="this.src='Images/add_plus_1.gif'"
        onmouseover="this.src='Images/add_plus_2.gif'"
        onmousedown"this.src='Images/add_plus_3.gif'"
        CauseValidation="false" style="cursor: pointer"
        OnClientClick="Javascript:SL_AddBuilding()" />
</asp:TableCell>
```

I think all the mouse event attributes are legit, so I don't know what it's complaining about.

Comment: While it works, you should add onmouseout, onmouseover, onmousedown via the image button's attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you copied it verbatim from your code you are missing an equal sign:

onmousedown"this.src='Images/add_plus_3.gif'"

Comment: Thanks, Eagle Eye. Now why couldn't the silly interpreter have told me this?

Comment: onmousedown="this.src='Images/add_plus_3.gif'" missing equals - DASH is right.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="imgAdd" src="Images/add_plus_1.gif"
    onmouseout="this.src='Images/add_plus_1.gif'"
    onmouseover="this.src='Images/add_plus_2.gif'"
    onmousedown="this.src='Images/add_plus_3.gif'"
    CauseValidation="false" style="cursor: pointer"
    OnClientClick="Javascript:SL_AddBuilding()" />
```