# How to Track button press event for asp.net in C# webform?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, webforms

I am trying to create a website in asp.net. I want to change ImageButton's image in pressed and unpressed state both.

So I need both pressed event and unpressed event in CSharp. How can I get that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mouse down and mouse up events are not supported in sever-side code because of potential performance issues. However, you can write some client-side code which can trigger the wanted behaviour. I would advise writing javascript code for this.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmousedown.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseup.asp

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try and mark it as an answer... I am new to asp.net :)

Comment: Good luck and keep rocking :)

Comment: On mouse down is not present in my aspx page

Comment: You must write a .js script and put the onmousedown function invocations in html.

Comment: In asp:ImageButton only onclick event is present

Comment: @BharatSharma check this question out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749468/imagebutton-with-mouse-event-handlers-considered-not-well-formed